# Django Storing Serialized JSON data

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, jsonb

Using the Django REST framework I have been serializing data for Invoices with the purpose of using the JSON for a search. In order to have the JSON in the correct format, I have had to serialize foreign key models (Customers, Products, etc) with their own serializers, and this process (as more and more invoices are created) has begun to take an unacceptably long time. My thought to fix this was to store all serialized invoices in the database, and when an invoice is created, serialize that new invoice and add it to the database. When an existing invoice is edited, update the JSON in the database with the new information. As of now, every time my view is loaded, ALL of the invoices are serialized, where as here we would serialize on when there is an add/edit/delete.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? I found Django has a JSONField so maybe I could create a new model to hold this JSON data? If so should I store all of the serialized invoices in one field? Or have foreign keys of each invoices JSON data that point to that new model? Maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your approach will take up more memory than it is required. You should use `pagination` and optimise the queries with `select_related` and `prefetch_related` (if you haven't already).

Comment: Why not use a Document Database to store this as a derived value? You are basically doing Denormalization here. I'd encourage you to think of using perhaps a secondary Mongo table for reads.

Comment: I am doing something similar - I have to query several tables to produce a graph for each one of my users. Even optimised, this takes too long. I plan on using the same approach you've just described (since graphs are updated once per quarter). I'll get back to you with results